# Confidence calculation in association rule

Tags: associations, tuples

```
supportData = {('ELF'): 0.75, ('CAT'): 0.75, ('BAT', 'CAT', 'ELF'): 0.5, ('ARK', 'BAT'): 0.25, ('ARK', 'ELF'): 0.25, ('CAT', 'ELF'): 0.5, ('DOG'): 0.25, ('BAT', 'CAT'): 0.5, ('BAT', 'ELF'): 0.75, ('ARK'): 0.5, ('ARK', 'CAT'): 0.5, ('BAT'): 0.75}

L = [('ARK'), ('CAT'), ('CAT'), ('ELF'),('ARK', 'CAT'), ('BAT', 'ELF'), ('BAT', 'CAT'), ('CAT', 'ELF'),('BAT', 'CAT', 'ELF')]


for freqSet in L:
    H =  list(freqSet)

    if len(H) == 1:
        pass
    else:
        for conseq in H:
            freqsetlist = list(freqSet)
            freqsetlist.remove(conseq)
            if len(freqsetlist) == 1:
               conf = supportData[freqSet]/supportData[tuple(freqsetlist)[0]]
               if conf >= 0.1:
                  print freqsetlist,'-->',conseq,'conf:',conf
            else:
               conf = supportData[freqSet]/supportData[tuple(freqsetlist)[:]]
               if conf >= 0.1:
                  print freqsetlist,'-->',conseq,'conf:',conf


KeyError: ('R','K')
```

Can someone point out why I am getting this error? It seems the error occur when len(freqsetlist) is > 1. That is when calculating tuple with 3 element

Comment: [3 weeks later](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137232/confidence-calculation-in-association-rule), no, we still can't.

Answer (score 0):

When a tuple has only one element, you should put a comma after it, so it will be interpreted as a tuple, and not as a single (parenthesized) element:

```
'CAT' == ('CAT') != ('CAT',) == tuple(['CAT'])
```

Since both your `supportData` and `L` variables are currently mixing strings and tuples (when you, I guess, only wanted to have tuples), this line of code for instance will never run:

```
if len(H) == 1:
    pass
```

**Update:** as for your error message, take the first element, `('ARK')`: you first converted it to a list (`['A', 'R', 'K']`), then removed the first element (`'A'`), then converted the result back to a tuple - yielding `('R', 'K')`. When you tried to look it up in your `supportData` dict (in the same line of code you mentioned) it wasn't there, thus a `KeyError`.

Correct your data as I explained, and this particular error will be avoided:

```
supportData = {('ELF',): 0.75, ('CAT',): 0.75, ('BAT', 'CAT', 'ELF'): 0.5, ('ARK', 'BAT'): 0.25, ('ARK', 'ELF'): 0.25, ('CAT', 'ELF'): 0.5, ('DOG',): 0.25, ('BAT', 'CAT'): 0.5, ('BAT', 'ELF'): 0.75, ('ARK',): 0.5, ('ARK', 'CAT'): 0.5, ('BAT',): 0.75}

L = [('ARK',), ('CAT',), ('CAT',), ('ELF',),('ARK', 'CAT'), ('BAT', 'ELF'), ('BAT', 'CAT'), ('CAT', 'ELF'),('BAT', 'CAT', 'ELF')]
```

Comment: The error is in this line  conf = supportData[freqSet]/supportData[tuple(freqsetlist)[:]]. Everything else works fine

Comment: This is consequence of the problem I explained in the answer. For more details, check the update above. See also [this](http://bugs.python.org/issue2817), in case I wasn't clear.